# How to get push notification when a file in google drive changes using google api

Tags: google-drive-api

Are there any ways of getting file changes pushed to your website if a user signed up with google drive? For my site, I am doing some post processing on google documents, and it would be nice if i can get user to identify files they would like to track and every time they change the file, I will automatically get a notification and I can download the new version on my end.

I tried searching around on google drive api page, and i can only find "realtime api" which seem to be an api to sync changes between two of my own files, and not push changes to me from google drive.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

This feature has been launched today. https://developers.google.com/drive/push?hl=en

Comment: Is it possible to get push notifications for any file change without a required web server in Python?

Comment: @Ali Afshar, How to get filename that is changing on drive in push notification.

Answer (score 1):

Notifications for updates on file/directory changes are not available at the moment. Drive team is considering this as a future feature.

Answer (score 1):

No push notification, but you can poll the "Changes Feed."

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-changes

Answer (score -4):

As an alternative, you can have a look at **[gdrive2slack](https://github.com/optionfactory/gdrive2slack)** project source to see an example of implementation without the use of push API. We poll Drive to have better control of the rate and than push notifications to Slack.